# How to change background color of UITextField to custom gradient color in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, gradient

I have done gradient coloring before for changing color of my parent view now I am using same method to change the background color of UITextField but its not working.

This is the method I used for my view:

```
 func setGradientBackgroundOfView()
{
    // assigning gradient color to background View

    let endingColorOFGradient = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 133/255, green: 210/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    let startingColorOfGradient = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 50/255, green: 189/255, blue: 170/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    gradient.colors = [startingColorOfGradient , endingColorOFGradient]
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)

}
```

And this method for setting layer:

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

I am calling my setGradientBackgroundOfView() in  viewDidLoad() and it's working perfect but if I change

```
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

with

```
self.textFieldUserName.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

it does not work. What am I missing here?